# Summing values into new sheet for unique dates and unique names

Tags: excel, vba

So here is my scenario, I already have a sub that extracts unique names and unique dates from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 creating the layout of unique names as rows and dates as headers. In Sheet 1 is the master data. For each day of the month, there are different work shifts for the same person. For example...

[image]

D Gray worked 3 different shifts on 6/26 so i need the values in Hours summed and then populated into Sheet 2 under the respective 6/26 date and so on and so forth for the other crew members. The template so far is..

[image]

[Result of New Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LFGZ.png)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `SUMIFS`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the image, but I understand your concept so hopefully you can apply the below to your case and use this as your answer.

Say the data in Sheet1 is columned as Date, Name, & Hours worked for A,B, & C respectively (for only 100 rows), your `SUMIFS` function in sheet2 should be as follows:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$100,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,B$2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100,$A2)`

This as you drag it down will hold the first column in sheet2, the names, and the first row in sheet2 the dates, summing up all the hours worked for all the days of the month.

If you use table formatting you can simply this further and the formula will resize with the table since it would use named ranges. I can help you with that as well if you'd like.

To have VBA add this formula to your spreadsheet use the following:

```
Dim RangeFormula As Range
Set RangeFormula = Sheet("Sheet2").Range( [input cell range here])
RangeFormula.Formula ="=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C$1:$C$100,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,B$2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100,$A2)
```

You can change the name from RangeFormula to whatever suits better, you can put the sheet name where Sheet2 is but make sure you put the cell range in the range part with " surrounding it. To reference this as a table you'll need to use the `ListObjects("Table Name")`

Comment: thank you for your comment @Mark S. Just to clarify, this is to be created in VBA? I have 2 other macros that will run in the same instance. `Sub MacroAll()
    test
    CopyUnique
End Sub`   So would I just add that SumIfs Sub after the CopyUnique Sub?

Comment: If you wanted to add this to your VBA you would want to fill in the data range with the vba function that inputs the actual excel function. I'll add this to my answer and you can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I added the syntax on how to use VBA to add a formula to your spreadsheet if this answers your question or sufficiently allows you to modify it to suit your specific needs please mark it as such :) Best of luck!

Comment: Most of it worked but it is not adding up any values, just "0". My Name field is B, Date is F, and Hours is G. My `"=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$100,Sheet1!$G$2:$G$100,B$2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100,$A2)"` Looks like this. Sorry, I am new to VBA and I apologize for the questions. @Mark S.

Comment: No problem @DaveNilges, the syntax for the sumifs formula is the following seperated by commas.
Sum Range, Criteria Range1, Criteria 1, Criteria Range 2, Criteria 2, etc.)

What this means is make sure that the critera range 1 matches the criteria. So if your name field is B, make sure the corresponding criteria on the sheet you're summing up in is lined up correctly. Before putting it into VBA put it into the spreadsheet and make sure it calculates that way first, the copy the formula into the VBA to fill in the rest.

Comment: The first thing I notice is your sumifs has column F as what's being summed but you said G, so it should be
`"=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$G$2:$G$100,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100,B$2,Sheet1!$F$1:$F$100,$A2)"`
This assumes in the new sheet the dates are across the row 1, and the names go down column A. It also assumes your other sheet only has 100 rows, so adjust the range accordingly to fit your data. Alternatively consider using a table format by hitting `CTRL + T`. This will allow more dynamic coding.

Comment: `Sub Add()

Dim RangeFormula As Range
Set RangeFormula = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(["B2:T5"])
RangeFormula.Formula = "=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$100,Sheet1!$G$2:$G$100,B$2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100,$A2)"
End Sub` This is the whole formula that I have. I will attach an image to the original question of the result I am getting.

Comment: `Sub Add() Dim RangeFormula As Range Set RangeFormula = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:T5") RangeFormula.Formula = "=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$F$2:$F$100,Sheet1!$G$2:$G$100,B$2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$100,$A2)" End Sub`
I took out the [], this was just used to denote an input. Sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: But also make sure to adjust the cell ranges which look like A1:A100 to fit your dataset, this can even be $A:$A, but this can weigh down on the system since it will read all the rows even if there isn't data.

Comment: When you say Cell Ranges are you talking about the $F$2:$F$100 ranges inside the SumIfs formula? should there be absolute cell referencing ($) in there?

Comment: Yes I'm referencing to that part of it. The $ should be there, that way as the formula gets moved throughout your sheet the references remain the same.